# Adding fully responsive typography to Bootstrap 3. Is that Possible? Take a look here

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, less

This is the question I've googled for a while today, unless I run into [this page](http://www.thedotmack.com/tags/Bootstrap,-Responsive,-Typography/). The author of this blog suggests to use some LESS mixins to make the size of the typographic elements vary depending on the screen size using media queries.

After reading the article, I've followed a blog about how to [customize Bootstrap 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594098/How-to-customize-Twitter-Bootstrap-to-fit-your-web) in order to get the basics to give it a try and I managed to integrate everything in Play Framework using sbt-less plugin.

Now, premising I'm the farthest thing in the universe from a web designer - I'm struggling to make a web app just for fun - and I read today for the first time something about LESS, I followed my instinct about how to integrate the mixins in Bootstrap code and I tryied this:

- created the responsive-typography.less file containing the code from the blog
- modified my custom-bootstrap file including it, like this:

  ```
  @framework: "lib/bootstrap/less"; // path to Bootstrap's "less" directory

  // Core variables and mixins
  @import "custom-variables.less";  // my customized variable file
  @import "@{framework}/mixins.less";
  @import "responsive-typography.less";  // code from the blog

  // Reset and dependencies
  @import "@{framework}/normalize.less";
  @import "@{framework}/print.less";
  ....
  ```

As a result, I see that everything takes the smallest font I set up in the responsive-typography.less file, no matter the screen size. Here's how I modified the file from the blog:

```
@xxs: ~'min-width: 377px';
@xs:  ~'min-width: @{screen-xs-min}';
@sm:  ~'min-width: @{screen-sm-min}';
@md:  ~'min-width: @{screen-md-min}';


.bs3-responsive-type(@mq, @font-size-base, @mq-size-percentage) {
   @media(@mq) {

     @font-size-large:    ceil((@font-size-base * 1.25)  * @mq-size-percentage);
     @font-size-small:    ceil((@font-size-base * 0.85)  * @mq-size-percentage);
     @font-size-h1:       floor((@font-size-base * 2.6)  * @mq-size-percentage);
     @font-size-h2:       floor((@font-size-base * 2.15) * @mq-size-percentage);
     @font-size-h3:       ceil((@font-size-base * 1.7)   * @mq-size-percentage);
     @font-size-h4:       ceil((@font-size-base * 1.25)  * @mq-size-percentage);
     @font-size-h5:       @font-size-base;
     @font-size-h6:       ceil((@font-size-base * 0.85)  * @mq-size-percentage);
     @import (multiple) "lib/bootstrap/less/scaffolding.less";
     @import (multiple) "lib/bootstrap/less/type.less";
   }
}

.bs3-responsive-type(@sm,  13px, 0.85);  
.bs3-responsive-type(@xs,  12px, 0.8);
.bs3-responsive-type(@xxs, 11px, 0.75); /* Everything takes this font even on large devices */
```

Comment: I assume you did not forget to *not* include default "scaffolding.less" and "type.less" within the rest of your main file imports list, did you? Also note that putting your "responsive-typography.less" at the very beginning of the imports list is not quite correct since it's too easily overridden by further imports (for instance most of the font properties you specified there are reset/overridden by "normalize.less" styles imported later).

Comment: My custom-bootstrap file is the almost exact copy of the original. I just added responsive-typography.less. Should I put it at the end of the file?

Comment: Not necessary at the end but at least not earlier than the original "scaffolding.less" and "type.less" imports (which you don't really need anymore). Otherwise as I said all your custom styles are overridden by those original styles.

Comment: Ouch! I found out I saw no changes because of the browser cache. But there's something not working related to media queries. I updated the question with further details.

Comment: Might the problem not be that the `responsive-typography.less` tries to create a media query including the content from `scaffolding.less` and `type.less`? If you simply copied the file from the blog it refers to a directory like `../../../hoverboard/`

Comment: I changed the path to the original bootstrap files on my file system

Comment: I think I managed to get it to work, how can I show you?

Comment: Me too!!!! Look the answer... If you did something different, let me know... I'm curious

Comment: Cool! I created a `bootstrap-customized.less` that first imports the default `bootstrap.less` and then the `responsive-typography.less`. Good enough for this example, but might have issues with font icon references I guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68077/discussion-between-ckuijjer-and-max).

Answer (score 0):

As en experiment I reverted the order of the last three lines and everything works. I got a fully responsive behaviour.

```
.bs3-responsive-type(@xxs, 11px, 0.75);  
.bs3-responsive-type(@xs,  12px, 0.8);
.bs3-responsive-type(@sm,  13px, 0.85);
```

The matter was the author in it's original post used the "max-" variables, I used the "min-"  ( as he suggested in the blog for a "mobile first" approach) so I needed to revert the lines.

So here's a brief resume:

responsive-typography.less file:

```
/**
 * Responsive typographic mixins
 * http://www.thedotmack.com/tags/Bootstrap,-Responsive,-Typography/
 */

/** Use these settings if you DON'T want a mobile first approach
@xxs: ~'max-width: 377px';
@xs:  ~'max-width: @{screen-xs-max}';
@sm:  ~'max-width: @{screen-sm-max}';
@md:  ~'max-width: @{screen-md-max}';
*/

@xxs: ~'min-width: 80px';
@xs:  ~'min-width: @{screen-xs-min}';
@sm:  ~'min-width: @{screen-sm-min}';
@md:  ~'min-width: @{screen-md-min}';


.bs3-responsive-type(@mq, @font-size-base, @mq-size-percentage) {
    @media(@mq) {

        @font-size-large:    ceil((@font-size-base * 1.25)  * @mq-size-percentage);
        @font-size-small:    ceil((@font-size-base * 0.85)  * @mq-size-percentage);
        @font-size-h1:       floor((@font-size-base * 2.6)  * @mq-size-percentage);
        @font-size-h2:       floor((@font-size-base * 2.15) * @mq-size-percentage);
        @font-size-h3:       ceil((@font-size-base * 1.7)   * @mq-size-percentage);
        @font-size-h4:       ceil((@font-size-base * 1.25)  * @mq-size-percentage);
        @font-size-h5:       @font-size-base;
        @font-size-h6:       ceil((@font-size-base * 0.85)  * @mq-size-percentage);
        @import (multiple) "lib/bootstrap/less/scaffolding.less";
        @import (multiple) "lib/bootstrap/less/type.less";
    }
}

/* IMPORTANT * Revert these lines if you want to switch to 'max-' variables */
.bs3-responsive-type(@xxs, 11px, 0.75);
.bs3-responsive-type(@xs,  12px, 0.8);
.bs3-responsive-type(@sm,  13px, 0.85);
.bs3-responsive-type(@md,  14px, 0.9);
```

Import this file after everything else. I set it as the last import in my custom-bootstrap.less

A final consideration: the original script works just fine, if you want to use the "min-" values, you need to change a few things. So i suggest to use the original script, not this version.

One more thing: there's a comment from ckuijjer where he states a possible problem with icon reference. I'm using fontawesome, and everything works like a charm. I haven't tried glyphicons yet.